# What is the best path to turn this design into a website?

Tags: html, css

sorry if this isn't the right place to ask. I'm someone with a little bit of experience in HTML and CSS, and I'm trying to build a website. I've made an animation that shows the exact design, but how each individual thing will be integrated/developed is less relevant to me now. I want to understand what is the best method for me to dive into the project of building this website. I definitely want whatever path is easiest, as I don't intend on becoming a web developer at the moment.

https://imgur.com/a/YYUYjbX

I've tried Squarespace, Framer and Webflow. I'm not sure where these services land in terms of what architecture they use (if that is even a term). All I know is I cannot use them for the functionality I need, which is to be able to toggle a "night mode" switch that changes content on the website. There are some ways to change the "theme" to a dark mode, but what I want is to be able to change pictures, text and other things, depending on what mode you are on ("light" or "dark"). That is the biggest priority, finding what tool/language of coding is best to achieve this functionality. I also need to be able to make a footer that expands a little when hovered over, and fully expands on click.

As you can see by my jargon, I really don't know enough to even gather what it is I'm getting into, but hey you only live once.

In an ideal world this would be achieved by me buying a CSS template and making some adjustments (which is what I've done in the past, through CSS). I'm totally willing to put hours into this, I just want to be pointed in the right direction. Am I meant to build this on HTML? Wordpress? Webflow?

Thanks!